# Estimate about primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples

Can anyone give an estimate (upper bound or lower bound) for the number of divisors $d\mid P_r$ such that $\frac{\sqrt{P_r}}{2}< d < \sqrt{P_r}$, where $P_r$ is the product of the $r$ smallest primes?

Comment: Yes.  About r choose (r/2).  (It might even be a good estimate.)  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.23

Comment: I would be more interested in the sum over products of last primes. Jokes aside, very bad way of stating the question...

Comment: The question *might* be better received if it gave more context, more illustration of what the OP has already tried or learned, and followed suggestions in http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: @Gerhard: I don't immediately see why $r$ choose $r/2$ is either an upper bound or a lower bound for the quantity in question.

Comment: I could have messed up.  I view the problem as specifying a certain antichain in a Boolean lattice of r atoms.  I think r choose r/2 is an upper bound, and for large r the lower bound might be something like r choose r/3, but I don't have a proof.  What is your take on it?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman,  2012.01.24

Comment: In fact, if we use exp(p_r) as a good asymptotic to P_r, then I think the desired quantity approaches r choose r/2 as r grows.  But you should get an estimate from a professional.  No one pays me for my guesses.  Yet.  Gerhard "They're Still Worth Something, However" Paseman, 2012.01.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be such that $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x} \sim r$, so that $P_r$ is about $e^x$. Let $\Psi(x,y)$ be the de Bruijn, function, the number of [$y$-smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) numbers less than or equal to $x$. So a crude upper bound for the quantity in question is about

$$
\Psi(e^{x/2},x) - \Psi(e^{x/2}/2,x).
$$

Out of these numbers (call the set of these numbers $X$) we want to get the squarefree ones. The proportion of squarefree numbers in all the integers is $1/\zeta(2)$ so it is tempting to use $|X|/\zeta(2)$ or $|X|\prod_{p\leq x}\left(1-1/p^2\right)$ as a crude first approximation, though I'm not sure how far off it is. The thing is that one is dealing here with only $x$-smooth numbers. Perhaps for each $p \leq z \ll x$ for suitable $z$ one can estimate the size of the subset of $X$ that is in $p^2\mathbb{Z}$, then use a simple inclusion-exclusion sieve to estimate the size of the subset of $X$ of numbers that, if they are divisible by prime squares $p^2$, must have $z \leq p\leq x$. Or, use more powerful sieve methods. (Guessing that sieving for squarefree numbers should be very similar to sieving for primes.)

Good references:

A. Granville, Smooth numbers: computational number theory and beyond, Algorithmic Number Theory, MSRI Publications, Volume 44, 2008.

T. Tao's blog, 254B, Notes 7: Sieving and expanders.

Answer (score 6):

Gerhard did not mess up. $\binom{r}{r/2}$ (or more precisely, the central binomial coefficient, but say $r$ is even) is an upper bound. If we shuffle the primes and multiply them together in random order, then the probability that we hit a given product of $k$ primes is $1/\binom{r}{k}$ (since it requires the first $k$ primes  to be a specified set), and therefore at least $$\frac1{\binom{r}{r/2}}.$$ It follows that the probability that some partial product is in the given interval is at least $N/\binom{r}{r/2}$, where $N$ is the number of divisors in the given interval (since we never stay in such a short interval).

Being a probability, this number is at most 1, which gives Gerhard's bound. My guess is that in reality that probability is more like $\log 2/\log r$, since if instead we add up the logarithms of the primes, we move in steps of size roughly $\log (r\log r) \sim \log r$, and we look for the probability of hitting an interval of length $\log 2$. This would suggest that $$N\approx \frac{\log 2}{\log r}\cdot \binom{r}{r/2}.$$
Edit: I'm fairly convinced that $N$ is of order $\binom{r}{r/2}/\log r$, but I'm not so sure about the constant $\log 2$, though it seems it gives asymptotically an upper bound.

Comment: IIUIC Gerhard’s argument was to apply Sperner’s theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem).

Comment: Yes, this is Sperner's theorem. I just love the proof so much I want to spell it out every time I use it :) 
 

Comment: I made my comments a bit cryptic so as to tease out of the original poster some motivation.  I like your answer, but I and others would be enlightened by a parenthetical phrase such as "(imagine walking from bottom to top along this randomly chosen chain in the Boolean lattice, hoping to meet this divisor)" .  It took me longer to understand your argument without the phrase than it did to come up with the initial estimate.  I like the probabilistic refinement.  The estimate feels right to me.
Gerhard "Don't You Feel Mathematics Too?"I Paseman, 2012.01.24

Comment: Guys thank yo very much for comments, I was not convinced by probabilistic method because its not always a proof. For example the probability of a number be co-prime to $p$ is (1-1/p) ans so the probability of a number be co-prime to set of primes is $\prod_{p \in P} (1-1/p)$. If we use this argument to count the prime numbers less than $X$, we have 
$\pi(X)= \prod_{p<\sqrt(X)} (1-1/p)X$ which is wrong by PNT and Mertens' theorems. Furthermore by the same argument the number less than $X$ which is co-prime to product of the all prime less than $X$ is  $\prod_{p<X} (1-1/p)X$  real value is $0$.

Comment: Arya, I would like to know the source and the motivation for this problem.  If you provide that, I would be willing to produce some non-rigorous algebraic/analytic justification of the bounds.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.24

Comment: we were interested to have a bound on $$\sum_{n \in B} \sum_{ d|n \; X<d<2X} 1 $$ where B is a subset of $[x^2,4X^2]$.

 so the worst case in the sum is when $n$ has large number of prime factors. 

Comment: In which case I think you can get much better bounds than the worst case.  I suspect an upper bound for this new sum is X^2.  I will think about it.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.24

Comment: Indeed, I think the new sum has a trivial upperbound of 4X^2, abd that can probably be improved upon.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.24

Comment: In fact, I think 2.8 X^2 is near optimal, and I will be happy to show that to you, although you might prefer to find it yourself.  Of course, if B has special characteristics, one might do better still.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.24

Comment: $B$ is a subset of $[X^2, 4X^{2}]$. The size of $B$ is very small, smaller than $X^{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Then one can get $O(X^{1+\epsilon})$, although I won't begrudge you the aadditional $\sqrt{\log X}}$ savings from the other argument if you really want it.
Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.01.24