# Square integral of finite Euler product

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series, euler-product

Consider the finite Euler product 
$$
P(t) = \prod_{r=1}^R \left(1 + p_r^{i t} \right).
$$
(Here $p_1, p_2, \dots$ are of course the primes.)

Question: What is a good asymptotic upper bound for 
$$
\int_0^T \left| P(t) \right|^2 dt,
$$
where $T = c^R$ for some *fixed* constant $c$ (you may choose any value of $c>1$ such as $c=1.1$ or $c=100$, obtaining a good result for any of these would be sufficient).

**In particular, is it true that this integral is $\mathcal{O} (2^R T)$?**

Remark 1: A trivial upper bound is $4^R T$.

Remark 2: If $R \leq \hat{c} \frac{\log T}{\log \log T}$ for some sufficiently small $\hat{c}$, then the integral actually is bounded by $2^R T (1+ o(1))$ by standard mean value theorems for Dirichlet series.

Remark 3: If you simply try to multiply out everything, you end up with problems of the kind discussed here: [Small quotients of smooth numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202316/small-quotients-of-smooth-numbers). Noam Elkies' heuristic there gives some indication on why the desired result should be true (for $c>3$). However, maybe there is a "holistic" (analytic?) approach which avoids multiplying out and using the worst-case estimate for every individual summand?